# Finding a hidden "heavy" subset of random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be independent non-negative random variables (with finite expectation and variance), and $0 < m < n$ be a fixed integer such that there exists a subset $S\subseteq [n]$ of size $\lvert S\rvert =m$ with

1. $\sum_{k\in S} \mathbb{E}[X_k] \geq 100$; and
2. $\sum_{k\notin S} \mathbb{E}[X_k] \leq 1$

and

1. $\sum_{k\in S} \operatorname{Var}[X_k] \leq \frac{1}{100} \left(\sum_{k\in S} \mathbb{E}[X_k]\right)^2$; and
2. $\sum_{k\notin S} \operatorname{Var}[X_k] \leq \frac{1}{100}$.

In other words, there is an unknown subset of elements that, altogether, are "heavy", and its complement is "light." If I define $T$ as the indices of the $2m$ top values among $X_1,\dots, X_n$, what is the probability that $\sum_{[n]\setminus T} \mathbb{E}[X_i] < 2$? (where the probability is taken over the realization of the $X_i$'s). In other terms, what is the probability that we removed (almost) all the weight of the"heavy set"?

If $m=1$, then this is clear that is happens with high probability by Chebyshev's inequality: if $S=\{i\}$, then the probability that $X_i$ is less than $50$ is at most $\frac{1}{25}$, and similarly the probability that the sum of all other elements (so a fortiori any of them) is greater than 2 is at most $\frac{1}{100}$, so that overall $X_i$ is the greatest element (and therefore among the two top elements) with probability at least $19/20$. Is there a way to generalize this argument to $m \geq 2$?

Comment: What if the variables are all constants (all variances are zero), $X_1=0$,  $X_2=200$, $X_i=1/2^i$ for $i>2$, and $S=\lbrace1,2\rbrace$? I think all inequalities are met and $\mathbb{P}(S\subset T)=0$ for all $n\ge5$ since you will always pick $T=\lbrace2,3,4,5\rbrace$.

Comment: @Enredanrestos: good point -- thanks! I reckon I messed up formalization the question (essentially, I don't care about the "spurious variables" in $S$, in your example $1$): the goal is to remove all the "heavy part." I'll edit my question...